# emacs tramp working with gnome-keyring-daemon

Tags: ssh, emacs, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring, tramp

Right now I have `gnome-keyring-daemon` set to start at login.  If I run `emacs -q` and then open a file on a server using `M-x find-file` and then enter a file on a remote server such as `/ssh:user@server:/home/user/.bashrc`, then a GUI pops up and asks for my ssh private key password.  I enter the correct password, and the file opens perfectly.

However, if the `gnome-keyring-daemon` password expires from the keyring, `emacs` still allows connection to the file without entering the password.  For example, let's say I open a remote file, then kill the file with `C-x k`.  Then I go to a terminal and type `ssh-add -D`.  I can verify that this causes the keyring to forget the password by running `ssh localhost` (the GUI pops up and asks for the password.)  But if I try and re-open the remote file in emacs using `C-x C-f M-p RET`, the file opens without requiring the password.

Running `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` fixes this issue i.e. the agent will correctly ask for a password if the key is not in the keyring.  Setting `tramp-persistency-file-name` to `nil` does not seem to change the behavior.

What is an efficient way to fix this problem?  Do I run `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` on some hook?  Maybe on a timer?  Does running this function have a negative impact on future tramp connections?

- emacs-version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1
- tramp-version: 2.2.6-24.3
- gnome-keyring-daemon --version: 3.2.2

**EDIT**

I'm now on a different computer with new versions of the relevant packages, but I still see the same behavior.

- emacs-version: GNU Emacs 24.4.2
- tramp-version: 2.2.9-24.4
- gnome-keyring-daemon --version: 3.10.1

I just ran the following steps:

1. Open emacs with `emacs -Q`
2. Eval `(require 'tramp)` and `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`
3. Open file on remote server using `tramp`; gnome-keyring-daemon GUI asked for SSH key password.
4. Killed the remote file using `C-x k`
5. In a terminal I ran `ssh-add -D` and verified that the password is no longer cached.
6. Re-opened remote file using `C-x C-f M-p RET`
7. Tramp opened file without asking for a password.

A copy of tramp's debug buffer is located at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VAUh4dH5).

Answer (score 0):

Tramp caches used passwords. You could disable this by `setq password-cache nil)`

Comment: While the documentation for `password-cache` certainly suggests that it would fix my issue, setting it to `nil` has no effect on the behavior. In fact, even with `password-cache` set to `nil` tramp will still cache passwords that aren't even related to `gnome-keyring-daemon`. For example using tramp to open local files with `sudo`, the sudo password seems to be cached until I explicitly cleanup the connection (even with a nil `password-cache`). Perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: Hmm, there is also `password-cache-expiry`, which you could try to set to `t`.

Comment: According to that variable's doc, it is how many seconds passwords should be cached. Setting to `nil` disables expiring. Mine is globally set to 16. Emacs won't allow setting it to `t`.

Comment: Oops, yes. `password-cache-expiry` is not the place to edit. Another source of a cached password could be auth-source.el, which is always enabled by default in Tramp. Hard to say whether it comes in play, without debugging Tramp. You could set `tramp-verbose` to 10, and rerun your tests with `emacs -Q`. I could try then to check the traces. Don't worry, Tramp wil **NOT** write any password string into the traces.

Comment: I just edited my question with a link to the tramp debug logs.

Comment: I've checked the traces. There is just one connection to the remote host, documented at 12:12:11.291237. There was no password request; likely because all password handling was done via ssh-agent. Tramp was not involved in password sending. When you deactivate ssh-agent as described, the Tramp connection is still active. Since there is no **new** Tramp connection, there is also no password request, and that's why the remote file is opened. Looks to me like the expected behaviour.